# Road map: beyond Artin-Wedderburn theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, cohomology, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

For a noncommutative semisimple ring $R$, its structure and its category of representations can be largely understood using [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem). Such structure theory is useful, for example, in the complex representation theory of finite groups $G$.

Every now and then, I encountered rings whose structures are more loose. For example, $\mathbb{F}[G]$, where the field isn't a nice as $\mathbb{C}$. Another example is the Borel-Moore homology $H(Z;\mathbb{C})$ of the Steinberg variety $Z$, which by [Deligne's decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_theorem) is semisimple modulo its nilradical [1, (8.6.11)].

I thus wish to expand my knowledge beyond A-W theorem, but I'm also aware that the theory could be less organized. Would you mind providing some pointers, or even better a road map? It'd be great if the abstract theory is accompany with some applications to important works like the above.

#### Reference

- [1] Representation theory and Complex Geometry by Chriss and Ginzburg.
- [2] https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913602/question-for-recommending-a-good-textbook-in-representation-of-quivers/914702

Comment: For finite dimensional algebras up to morita equivalence you can assume your algebra comes from a quiver with relations.  And this is a big subject.  Ralf Schiffler has a nice introduction

Comment: The introduction [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380877/road-map-beyond-artin-wedderburn-theorem#comment967656_380877) by @BenjaminSteinberg (probably):  [Ralf Schiffler - Quiver representations](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-09204-1).

Comment: @LSpice, yes thanks.

Comment: For semisimple algebras over a field $\mathbb F$, like $\mathbb F[G]$ (at least when the order of $G$ is nonzero in $F$), the key thing to generalize the Artin-Wedderburn picture is to understand the division algebras over the field, i.e. the central simple algebras over the extension fields. These are classified by the Brauer group of their extension fields. These concepts are presumably all points on the road map...